# Getting an empty Pandas series when slicing by index

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a pandas series

```
TimeUS
33715400    253.07
33715600    253.07
33715800    253.07
33716000    253.10
33716200    253.11
         ...  
34047400    253.15
34047600    253.04
34047800    252.89
34048000    252.90
40482000    252.95
```

I need to get a subset of this data, but when I call something like

```
s = data[33716200:]
```

I get an empty series. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want to slice using index but `data[33716200:]` will slice using row number. For index based slicing, try using `data.loc[33716200:]`